# Python patch object with a side_effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to have a Mock object return certain values based on the input given. I looked up a few examples on SO and for some reason I still can't get it to work. Here's what I have right now.

```
class EmailChecker():
    def is_email_correct(email):
        some regex to determine if email is valid, returns either True or False

def my_side_effect(**args):
    if args[0] == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False

myMock = mock.patch.object(EmailChecker, 'is_email_correct', side_effect=my_side_effect)
```

Yet it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why `**args` instead of `*args`?

Comment: `**args` checks for keyword arguments, `*args` checks for positional arguments. So as @falsetru mentions, you probably want `*args`.

Comment: Updated the code to give more context

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `patch.object` as a decorator or context manager, as in the following code:

```
>>> class EmailChecker():
...     def is_email_correct(self, email):
...         pass
... 
>>> def my_side_effect(*args):
...     if args[0] == '1':
...         return True
...     else:
...         return False
... 
>>> with mock.patch.object(EmailChecker, 'is_email_correct', side_effect=my_side_effect):
...     checker = EmailChecker()
...     print(checker.is_email_correct('1'))
...     print(checker.is_email_correct('2'))
... 
True
False
```

**NOTE**: Replaced `**args` with `*args`. Added missing `self` argument to `is_email_correct` method.

---

`my_side_effect` could be simplified as follows:

```
def my_side_effect(email): 
    return email == '1'
```

Comment: Must have been my use of **args on accident. Worked great! Thanks!

Comment: @congalong, I added a note about `my_side_effect`. Check it out.

Comment: Is there a way to get the "self" parameter that is normally in the original call inside the my_side_effect function?

Comment: `my_side_effect` will be called with `self`. Check `args[0]` or change the `my_side_effect` function signature to `def my_side_effect(self, *args)`

Comment: If you want to use a fixed number of arguments in your side-effect function i.e  `my_side_effect(self, arg1)` you need to pass `autospec=True` to `mock.patch.object` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20258218/309334)