# How to test/simulate broken database connection

Tags: django, django-testing

I have written logic to return custom errors when my application cannot connect to the database (why that can happen is out of the scope for this question). I wish to write unit tests for this, specifically to see the response status codes when:

1. there **is** a valid connection to the database. This is easy as Django automatically creates a "test" database whenever I run any tests.
2. there **isn't** a valid connection to the database. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation about this.

Is it possible to run that test by somehow simulating that something has gone wrong with the database connection?

Comment: what exactly you want to simulate that would work without having database connection

Comment: @iklinac Custom server errors

Comment: please elaborate in question, but wondering why don't you just raise your error in test

Comment: I can't raise an error as the logic I've written resides in a middleware. I create a cursor() to check if the connection exists. I doubt raising an error will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than simulating a failed connection, you could simply raise your custom error during the test.

```py
raise customConnectionError('oops')
```

Another possibility is using the `destroy_test_db` method from `django.db.connection.creation` to close the connection to your database.

```py
from django.db.connection.creation import destroy_test_db


destroy_test_db('your_database_name', keepdb=True)
```

For more information please consult [Django Docs: destroy_test_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.db.connection.creation.destroy_test_db).

Comment: I can't raise customConnectionError as I test connectivity by creating a cursor on on my `connection` object. 

As for connecting to a test database that doesn't exist, do you mean do that by using settings.py?  I'd probably be hesitant to do that as this is only a single unit test, it seems like too much overhead.

Comment: How about running it as you last test? You could destroy the test database after everything else is done and then attempt your connection. Maybe try
[destory_test_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.db.connection.creation.destroy_test_db)

Comment: Thanks @0p3r4t0r, that's an interesting idea!

Comment: Let me know how it turns out. I'll edit my answer if it works.

Comment: What you've pointed out does get pretty close: "If the keepdb argument is True, then the connection to the database will be closed, but the database will not be destroyed.". Seems like it is indeed what I want, except that my tests are throwing errors all over the place when I use it. 
However, if you update your answer with this info, I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've updated my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to achieve this is by using [mocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). You can have your middleware accept a `conn` object that defaults to None, then pass it a mock connection object that has a [side_effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107424/python-patch-object-with-a-side-effect) of being broken.

I've written an article about how to do this [here](https://a3y3.dev/cloud/2020/06/23/readiness-checks.html).

Comment: Please post the actual content, and not links to content, as the article is now gone, so this post isn't terribly helpful anymore.

Comment: I thought about deleting this answer but I realized this still contributes to the question by referencing mocks and side_effects. I've updated the broken link so it points to a live page, but I'm still leaving this answer here.